# Split a column in multiple columns using Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column `col1` that represents a GPS coordinate format:

> 25 4.1866N 55 8.3824E

I would like to split it in multiple columns based on white-space as separator, as in the output example `table_example` below:

```
| 1st_split  | 2nd_split   | 3rd_split    | 4th_split    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
|    25      |   4.1866N   |     55       |     8.3824E  |
```

Considering the fact that there is the split() function, I have tried in this way:

```
SELECT explode(split(`col1`, ' ')) AS `col` FROM table_example;
```

But, instead of splitting per multiple columns, it splits per multiple rows, like in the output below:

[image: output]

Can someone clarify me which would be the worth approach for get the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a dataframe as

```
+---------------------+
|col                  |
+---------------------+
|25 4.1866N 55 8.3824E|
+---------------------+
```

**Using Scala API**

You can simply use `split` *inbuilt function* and `select` appropriately as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("split", split(col("col"), " "))
    .select(col("split")(0).as("1st_split"), col("split")(1).as("2nd_split"),col("split")(2).as("3rd_split"),col("split")(3).as("4th_split"))
  .show(false)
```

which would give you

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|1st_split|2nd_split|3rd_split|4th_split|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|25       |4.1866N  |55       |8.3824E  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**Using SQL way**

`Sql` is much easier and similar to the api way

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_example")
val splitted = sqlContext.sql("SELECT split(`col`, ' ') AS `col` FROM table_example")

splitted.createOrReplaceTempView("splitted_table")
val result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT `col`[0] AS `1st_split`, `col`[1] AS `2nd_split`, `col`[2] AS `3rd_split`, `col`[3] AS `4th_split` FROM splitted_table")
result.show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: But this is slightly different from a standard SQL approach. I mean... I cannot use that syntax within a SQL context.

Comment: On your answer you're using pyspark syntax for dataframe I supposed.

Comment: Assuming that you cannot help me to solve the problem on SQL side, do you have an idea of how the same scala snippet would be represented using java, or python syntax?

Comment: Thanks for the SQL example! If you would provide me also a sort of java example it would be great. Cause the Scala example is not so useful for my case/scenario. I supposed that they would be quite similar.

Comment: This is what I was searching for (just plain SQL within just one query): SELECT 
`col`[0] AS `1st_split`, 
`col`[1] AS `2nd_split`, 
`col`[2] AS `3rd_split`, 
`col`[3] AS `4th_split` FROM (

SELECT split(`col`, ' ') AS `col` FROM example_table )... but you suggested me the right way with your SQL example :-)

Comment: great to hear that @UgoL and thanks for the upvote and acceptance